# Логический оператор

Tags: javascript

Поясните, пожалуйста, словами что означает подобная запись

```
 direction == 1 &&  (offset=0)
```

возможно ли её переписать в более привычной форме, например через условную конструкцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверить значение **direction** и если оно *равно* **1**, то *выставить* **offset** в **0**;

все выражение

- вернет **0**, если  **direction** *равно* **1**
- вернет **false** если **direction** *не равно* **1**

насчёт переписать, смотря как оно используется. можно так, но будет лишнее присваивание и offset должен быть объявлен заранее.

```
((offset=direction==1?0:offset) && false)
```

можно так

```
if (direction==1) offset=0;
```

но тогда не вернется результат проверки direction.

Comment: Насчет результата неправда. Если direction равно 1, то результат **0**, если не 1, то результат **false**. Именно так, 0 и false.

Comment: видимо меня вывод консоли подвел, ну тогда просто if будет даже правильнее вряд-ли кто-то всерьез разделяет 0 и false

Comment: @eicto, ну смотря в каких функциях :) навскидку PHP функция [strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)...
> Возвращает позицию, в которой находится искомая строка, относительно начала строки haystack (независимо от смещения (offset). Также обратите внимание на то, что позиция строки отсчитывается от 0, а не от 1.

Comment: @thunder я имел в данном конкретном примере, конечно можно разделить, но проще тогда уж сделать 0/1

Comment: @eicto, просто писать, что 
> вряд-ли кто-то всерьез разделяет 0 и false

плохо! Разделять их нужно, потому что если приучиться их не разделять, то потом будут детсадовские вопросы "а почему..." :) Я к тому, что этой строчкой подаете плохой пример :)

Comment: ну я своим исправленным примером же показал, что эта возможность важна, да и специально обратил внимание на важность того что вернет выражение в целом, кстати до сих пор не понимаю как я получил  утренний результат, наверное спал почти. про false я вот что имею ввиду, чтобы использовать такой результат надо писать что-то типа

    if ((direction == 1 &&  (offset=0))===false) run();

или например

    var out=(direction == 1 &&  (offset=0))===false?1:2;


что уже монстроидно выглядит.